# Logging slow redis operations in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

In the Nodejs app, I am using 'ioredis' npm module to execute all redis operations. Redis is used heavily in the whole service. But I have seen for 1 of 1000 call, redis latency is increased to 400ms.

I am trying to log all redis operations exceeding a certain timestamp in the code itself. Suggest some ways to log such commands, without slowing any other operation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
var Moment = require('moment');

var start_time = Moment();


//->>> In case of Promises

redisOperation(arguments)
.then(function() {
   var time_taken = Moment() - start_time;
   console.log(time_taken); //However you want to log, use the logger function here
});



//->>> In case of Callback Function

redisOperation(arguments, function() {
    var time_taken = Moment() - start_time;
    console.log(time_taken); //However you want to log, use the logger function here

    cb();
});
```

Comment: Hey Prerna, Thanks for replying. I explored this option, but this is causing additional overhead. Is there any other better in-build operation from ioredis module or something similar to tthat.

Comment: ok, no idea yet Pavneet about any in-build operation for ioredis that could give you response time for that specific function, to be called. Will mention here if at all I come across any.

Comment: You can give this method also a try :
************
console.time("redis_function") and console.timeEnd("redis_function")
************
This will actually reduce the overhead of importing any module like Moment, for example.

Answer (score 0):

For time being, I wasn't able to find any inbuilt solution. But I handled this by creating a wrapper before the execution of Redis operations.

```
const traceTime = function (fn) {
   return async function (...args) {
      const startTime = Date.now();
      const executionResp = await fn.apply(this, args);
      const endTime = Date.now();
   };
}

/* wrap the redis operations with traceTime */

set = traceTime(set); // redis set operation
get = traceTime(get); // redis get operation


/* use redis set operation, wherever you want to use,           
  it will log startTime and endTime and execute redis operation from there */
set(key, value, (err, response) => { 
   // err and response handler 
});
```